# PostgreSQL varchar length performance impact

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL which is under heavy load (reads). It is practically core table of an application. One column is used as a discriminator - column used by application, that determines type of entity (class) that represents given row. It has to be exactly one varchar column. Currently I do store full class name in it, like: `"bank_statement_transaction"`.

When application selects all bank statement transactions, query is built like `... WHERE Discriminator = 'bank_statement_transaction'` . This brings more readability and clarity to data, structure and code.

Table contains currently 3M rows and counting, approximately 100k new rows monthly. `Discriminator` was indexed during some performance tunings. I don't have any performance issues right now.

I am working on a new feature that requires some little refactoring and yeah I had an idea to change full class name (`bank_statement_transaction`) to short unique codes (`BST`)

I replicated dbo and changed full class name to code. With 3M rows, performance gain is barely measurable, same or 1-2 milliseconds faster.

Can anyone share experience with VARCHAR length impact on INDEX size and performance? On bigger data set? Is this change worth of it?

Comment: Do you have a finite list of `Discriminator`, and does your application need to dynamically add more possible `Discriminator`. perhaps a better solution would be to use `ENUM` type for this column. also, please update your question with more details for others to diagnose the performance characteristics, like what query are you using to benchmark, what is the output if you run explain, what are the index definitions

Comment: If I remember well they state it multiple times in the documentation, that there's no performance difference between the text types. Even text is the same as varchar. But when you create an index, you can decide how many characters to include in it. That will make a difference.

Comment: Bigger data - less performance. If you have limited amount of possible values of `Doscriminator` (BTW sounds strange a bit :) - look at [Enumerated Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html). Syntactically it is same  but takes significantly less storage space for long text values.

Comment: In short-term (weeks) the list is finite. In long-term (months to years) the list will grow. I will have a look on ENUM type, thanks a lot. I have a googled and I found that too. TEXT vs VARCHAR is no difference in the manner of performance. I am talking about size of data contained in it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

If you index strings, the index will become larger if the strings are long. The fan-out will be less, so the index will become deeper.

With an index scan that searches for a few rows, this won't be noticable: reading a few blocks more and running comparisons on longer strings may be lost in the noise for any but the simplest queries. Still, you'll be faster with smaller strings.

Maybe the most noticeable effect will be that a smaller index needs less RAM for caching, so the number of disk reads should go down.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience. I will have look on ENUM type though. Enum may make the difference even bigger.

Comment: Stay away from enums unless you are dead certain that you will never want to remove a label. A lookup table that maps the strings to integers is often better.

Comment: "Stay away from enums" - could you explain? What is the critical difference with  lookup tables/dictionaries except that the value can not be deleted?

Comment: That *is* the critical difference. If you know that you will never, ever, want to remove one of these stings, there is nothing wrong with enums. For example, I wouldn't use them to model the states of the USA - even though it has never happened in the past, there is no 100% guarantee that no state will ever secede.